# undefined index android to php

Tags: php, android

I  am  trying  to  send   a  username(log)  from  an  android  client  to  a  server  ( PHP file) ,  but   in  PHP  file  I  found  undefined  index  for  the  username  sent.

### Android code

```
    public class authentification extends Activity {

    Button Quitter, Annuler, Valider;
    EditText login,password;
    String logn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.authentification);
        Quitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Quitter);
        Valider = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Valider);
        Annuler = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Annuler);
        login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login);

        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);


        Valider.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                verifier_admin(v);

            }
        });


        Quitter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }


    public void reset(View v){
        login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        login.setText("");
        password.setText("");

    }


    public void verifier_admin(View v){
        InputStream is = null;
        HttpClient httpclient = null;
        HttpPost httppost = null;
        HttpResponse response = null;
        HttpEntity entity = null;
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = null; 
        String pass;
        String log = login.getText().toString();

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.100:80/android/connection.php");
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        //log = login.getText().toString();
        //pass =password.getText().toString();
        if(log.length()>0 ){

            try{

                List<NameValuePair> var = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();   
                var.add(new BasicNameValuePair("log",log));

                //var.add(new  BasicNameValuePair("pass",pass));
               // post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity (var,"utf-8"));
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity (var));
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();
                String reponse =client.execute(post,responseHandler);               
                //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                //String s = reader.readLine();
                Toast.makeText(this, "message envoyé",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                login.setText("");


            }
            catch(ClientProtocolException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(IOException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        else 
            Toast.makeText(this, "veuillez entrez vos données",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }



        }
```

### PHP file :

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST)  ){
$log=$_POST['log'];
print_r($_POST);

//connexion base
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ('ERREUR '.mysql_error()) ;
$bd_selected=mysql_select_db("mydb",$link) or die ('ERREUR1 '.mysql_error());
$req=" SELECT * FROM user WHERE (login = '$log')";

$sql=mysql_query($req); 
$data = mysql_num_rows($sql);
echo $data;
}
?>
```

$log=$_POST['log']; is undefined .

Comment: Please post your complete error message.

Comment: the problem is that the username sent from android ,can't be posted to php file . this the response of server Notice: Undefined index: log in C:\xampp\htdocs\android\connection.php on line 4
Array ( )